# How to execute a function that contains a react hook inside

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, auth0

I'm building an app with react and nodeJS. I want to make an API call and use a react hook inside this function to get a token from Auth0 to authenticate with the API.

```
async function CallApi(userId) {
  const { getTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const token = await getTokenSilently();
  try {
    const response = await fetch(process.env.API_URL + "users", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        user_id: userId
      }
    });

    var result = JSON.stringify(await response.json());

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  return result;
};

export default CallApi;
```

Now I want to call this function in another file:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ readError: null });
    try {
      var profile = await CallApi("own");
      this.setState({
        username: profile.username,
        email: profile.email
      })
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ readError: error.message });
    }
  }
```

Now if I want open this site I getting the error `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

What I am doing wrong and how can I achieve to get a token from this hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because use are using a hook call `useAuth0`==> you need to call it in a body of functional component or a customer hook which is have pre-fix `use` ==> you `CallApi` is not a hook ==> you got the error.

1. Create `useCallApi` hook.

```js
 
function useCallApi(userId) {
  const [result, setResult] = c()
  const { getTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const fetchResult = useCallback( async(userId) =>{
      const token = await getTokenSilently();
      try {
        setLoading(true)
        const response = await fetch(process.env.API_URL + "users", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            user_id: userId
          }
        });
        setLoading(false)
        var result = JSON.stringify(await response.json());
        setResult(result)
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false)
        setError(error)
        console.error(error);
      }
    },[userId])

  useEffect(() =>{
    if(userId){
       fetchResult()
    }
  },[userId])
  
  return {userInfor: result, loading, error,fetchResult};
};

export default useCallApi;
```

- Now I want to call this function in another file, but you need to
  convert your existing component to functional component and use
  `useCallApi` hook.
- IF you pass a string when you declare `useCallAPi` like this useCallAPi("own"), it will call the api dicrectly.
- You can also `const {result, fetchResult} = useCallAPi("own")` and call `fetchResult("own")` anywhere you want to fetch result

```js
//other import
import {useCallAPi} from "path_to/useCallApi.js"
// you need to convert your class compoenent to this compoenent
function AFunctionalComponent(userId) {
  const [readError, setReadError] = useState(null)
  // result include username and email walready
  const {result} = useCallAPi("own")


  return(
    // your ui render herer
  )
};
```

Updated: If you want to set local state base on `result` in the functional component you can try this

```js
//other import
import {useCallAPi} from "path_to/useCallApi.js"
// you need to convert your class compoenent to this compoenent
function AFunctionalComponent(userId) {
  const [readError, setReadError] = useState(null)
  const [useInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null)
  // result include username and email walready
  const {result} = useCallAPi("own")

  useEffect(() =>{
    if(result){
       setUserInfo({
          username: result. username,
          email: result.email
       })
    }
  },[result])

  return(
    // your ui render herer
  )
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks man for this. But I can't use `useCallApi()` in the async function `callApi`: `var profile = useCallApi("own");` ... The useCallApi will not be executed...

Comment: My bad forgetting to replace that, I updated my comment.

Comment: @Undex. I updated `useCallApi` to make it flexiable, and return more stuff, check it out

Comment: Awesome, it works now and I can finally call my backend API. But I have one more question... I want to change the result in the functional component through onChange functions and struggle to get the result into this: `const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(result)` or `const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({}); setUserInfo(userData);` but then the component makes an infinite loop. However I don't get data from this.

Comment: What onChange function are you talking about? you don't need `const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(result)` in functional component, if you want to call that api with another userId just call `fetchResult(newUserID)` at place you want.

Comment: I want to be able to change the result in my functional component after I get the result from the useCallApi. So I can in other functions set the email of the result from example@web.org to example123@web.org - https://hastebin.com/unomafewif.xml

Comment: If you want to have local state based on the `result` you can use `useEffect` to do that. check my updated comment.

Answer (score -1):

Took me forever to figure this out, but finally resulted going back to go ol' callbacks. Only thing that worked for me (because I HAD to call the hook from non-react context, all other's threw the know React Hook Call (outside functional component) error.
Btw, this setup makes any hook accessible from ANY (instantiated) context, even vanilla-js, like it my example!

Non-React or React Context:

```ts
class WhateverClass {
  private xyzHook: (XyzHookContextI) | undefined

  public setHookAccessor (xyzHook: XyzHookContextI): void {
    this.xyzHook = xyzHook
  }
      
  executeHook (): void {
    const hookResult = this.xyzHook?.specificHookFunction()
    ...
  }
}

export const Whatever = new WhateverClass() // singleton
```

Your hook (or your wrapper for an external Hook)

```tsx
export interface XyzHookContextI {
  specificHookFunction: () => Promise<string>
}

const XyzHookContext = createContext<XyzHookContextI>(undefined as any)

export function useXyzHook (): XyzHookContextI {
  return useContext(XyzHookContextI)
}

export function XyzHook (props: PropsWithChildren<{}>): JSX.Element | null {
  async function specificHookFunction (): Promise<void> {
    ...
  }

  const context: XyzHookContextI = {
    specificHookFunction
  }

  // and here comes the magic in wiring that hook up with the non function component context via callback
  Whatever.setHookAccessor(context)

  return (
    < XyzHookContext.Provider value={context}>
      {props.children}
    </XyzHookContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Voila, now you can use ANY react code (via hook) from any other context (class components, vanilla-js, …)!

(…hope I didn't make to many name change mistakes :P)

Comment: @undex You could just use the Whatever Class as a Hook-accesor for your Class-Component, basically avoiding refactoring Class-Components to Functional-Components

Answer (score -2):

https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

To avoid confusion, it’s not supported to call Hooks in other cases:

Do not call Hooks in class components.

Do not call in event handlers.

Do not call Hooks inside functions passed to useMemo, useReducer, or useEffect.

Comment: I know this site... But the hook isn't executed in a class component, in an event handler or uses useMemo, useReducer or useEffect. And I need a solution, because i don't know how to solve this and not copy and paste the warnings from the react js website.

Comment: this.setState({ readError: null }); -> this code is not called in a class componet?